# Grails Asset Pipeline: Regenerate Asset on Every Access

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline, assets, dynamically-generated

I have several JavaScript assets that contain data that is constantly changing.  One solution would be to use AJAX to retrieve this data, but I'm trying to keep things simpe and just have the data contained in the JavaScript asset file (I've setup a custom asset file type that uses the GSP template engine to parse any GSP tags in the JavaScript file ... that is where the constantly changing data is coming from).

The only thing I can't figure out is how to not pre-compile these assets during WAR file creation but instead recompile these assets every time they are requested so that the latest data is contained in them.  Is this even possible with the Asset Pipeline plugin?

Comment: If data is dymanic, it seems more complicated doing through Assets pluging versus simple AJAX call that spits out JSON directly from controller.

Answer (score 0):

To re-generate javascript files on every request seems to be the opposite of the asset-pipeline approach. Asset-pipeline is used to serve **static** assets (as described in the first sencence of the [docs](http://grails.org/plugin/asset-pipeline)).

The cleanest approach would be to get the static stuff into the asset-pipeline and do the dynamic data via ajax. Then you could even handle caching via http header much better (for the ajax calls).

However asset-pipeline has the possibility to embed script elements into the page with `<asset:script type="text/javascript" />` (as described in the section "Deferred Scripts" in the [docs](http://bertramdev.github.io/asset-pipeline/guide/usage.html#linking)). But this does not seem to be more clear, then the ajax calls. The other option you mentioned, if even possible, to declare some files to be regenerated seems not a good fit for the asset-pipeline.